# draw a graph of tangent in SVG using C

Tags: c, graph, svg, drawing

this is the last part of my a bit more complex homework which I can't figure out myself.

Basically it's a tangent function, drawn to SVG using C.

This is how I'm drawing it:

[image]

and this is how it should look like:

[image]

it's pretty much the same except I'm drawing even those lines where tangent isn't defined.. How do I get rid of that? I'm actually generating that tangent using a simple `for` cycle, and I understand by changing Lineto to Moveto I will get rid of those line, but how to determine a formula which will be usable for any height/width and any (-x,x) (-y,y). Any thoughts?

**Source codes**:
[link to my drawing](http://pastebin.com/GNzzvw7W) | [link to original drawing](http://pastebin.com/A0fD9LKP)

edit: structure

```
typedef struct svg_graph{
    int w;
    int h;
    int x;
    int y;
} graph;
```

and the code itself:

```
double initializer = 0;
double m = 0;
double temp = 0;

initializer = svg->h/2 - tan(-svg->x)*(((double)svg->h/2)/svg->y);
fprintf(output, "<path clip-path=\"url(#myClip)\" d=\"M 0 %.1f", initializer)
temp = ((double)svg->x/(svg->w/2));
m = svg->h/2 - tan(-svg->x+temp)*((double)(svg->h/2)/svg->y);
for (int i = 1; i<=svg->w; i++){

      fprintf(output, " L %d %.1f", i, m);

      temp = ((double)svg->x/(svg->w/2)) + temp;
      m = svg->h/2 - tan(-svg->x+temp)*((double)(svg->h/2)/svg->y);
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code that you use to generate this? I'm not hugely au fait with this stuff, but I should think (since you know the points at which the graph will go from +inf to -inf) it should be easy to know when to do a Moveto.

Comment: @halfer: edited the first post and added the desired piece of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the derivative is non-finite then you need a move rather than a line.

Comment: you mean derivative of tangent? or of those coordinates? Not sure if I caught on your idea.

Comment: if the co-ordinates are x, y then dy/dx is the derivative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative